# SQL Query To Delete All the Tables and its Schema in Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I want to delete couple of schema's and their tables in Azure Data Warehouse. I tried running the below command but it is giving me an error as below,

> "Msg 104472, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 SELECT statements do not
> support incremental operators, such as += or equivalent, when
> referencing a table."

SQL Query I executed below --

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

DECLARE @schema_name sysname = [Demo_POC];

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';'
FROM sys.tables
WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema_name);

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;

DROP SCHEMA [Demo_POC];

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

This query works fine for me in Azure SQL Servers but doesn't work in Azure Data Warehouse I tried updating it couple of times but didn't work.
Currently, I am using Drop table and Drop Schema commands which is time consuming for 50+ specific schema's.

Could you anyone please let me know how I can run the above query without any error in Azure Data warehouse?

Answer (score 1):

You can use STRING_AGG to define the @sql.

```
SELECT @sql = STRING_AGG(N'DROP TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@schema_name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(name) + ';', '')
FROM sys.tables
WHERE schema_id = SCHEMA_ID(@schema_name);
```

Also you fill the variable wrong:

```
DECLARE @schema_name sysname = [Demo_POC];
```

should be

```
DECLARE @schema_name sysname = 'Demo_POC';
```

(if you want the [], you should do the quotes outside of that of course :) )

Comment: Thanks for reply. Tried using the above change but the script has now started giving error as "Invalid column name 'Demo_POC'.
"  This Demo_POC is the schema name in the query. Not sure what does this means now.

Comment: thanks for prompt replies. Sorry I forgot to add that I already tried the schema name with single quotes but it didn't work and gave error as "Must declare the scalar variable "@schema_name".